# Performance of newing a List<T> with very large initial capacity and filling it versus simply filling a LinkedList<T>

Tags: c#, .net, performance, list, linked-list

Which is faster and why:

```
IEnumerable<T> clxnOfTs = GetSeriouslyHugeCollection();
var list = new List<T>(clxnOfTs.Count);
foreach (T t in clxnOfTs) list.Add(t);
```

or

```
IEnumerable<T> clxnOfTs = GetSeriouslyHugeCollection();
var linkedList = new LinkedList<T>();
foreach (T t in clxnOfTs) linkedList.Add(t);
```

Assume this will run on a newish multi-core server with loads of memory.

So really, the question is whether pre-allocating the array that underpins the List all at once and then filling it is faster than simply allocating each LinkedListNode as each T is added to the LinkedList.

My intuition says that allocating a very large chunk of contiguous memory all at once is more expensive than allocating many little chunks anywhere on the heap because it is unlikely that the chunk of contiguous memory will already exist.

Thanks!
Jeff

Comment: Why do you want to compare `LinkedList` with one technique against `List` with another? Kind of apples and oranges.

Comment: Why would you go to the effort of writing the code, pasting it into SO but then asking someone else to actually time it to see which one's faster?

Comment: The most relevant performance factor here is probably that using `IEnumerable::Count()` to decide how big to make your array means you end up iterating over the sequence twice.

Comment: Not sure that `LinkedList` has an `Add` method.  Do you have a specific one in mind, like `AddAfter` or something?

Comment: Also what is the point of duplicating the list returned from the method in the first place?

Comment: @Mike, nitpicky, but creating a list from an IEnumerable isn't duplicating anything. The object doesn't get iterated upon until you actually add it to a list (or do something else like count the elements). That is, `IEnumerable<T> x = ThingThatReturnsIenumerable()` causes nothing to happen until you do something with x. Unless the method is coded in an unfortunate way.

Comment: @jamietre, that is not what I meant. I mean he is getting his data from that method which returns a IEnumerable<T>. I am wondering then why he is looping through the returned results and then adding them to List<T>, basically we need more information then what is provided.

Comment: @Mike: The point of duplicating the IEnumerable is to run a test to see which method of populating a list is faster.

Comment: @Will: I certainly am testing this as we speak! But I like to get as much information as possible before the test, as it may inform my testing strategy. Simply timing the two loops can tell me which one is faster under the testing conditions, but I would like to have some insight into the "why."

Comment: @Anon.: Nice catch -- that's a bug. I should have used an ICollection so that the count is O(1).

Comment: @OmniJeff:  I  think 'Why is this faster than that?' is a reasonable question, but asking which is faster without looking like you've tried to find out is not the best way to get good results on SO.  People who've spent much time doing perf work will refrain from guessing anyway because they've guessed and been wrong so many times before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, as with any performance related question, if you really care about the answer you should create a reaslistic test harness, write the code both ways, and profile it.

But to address your question in a more general sense, I would offer some advice about the **scenarios** where different kinds of list structures make sense.

**`List<T>` makes sense (from a performace standpoint) when you generally add/remove items at the end of the list, and only rarely add or remove items in the middle.** It also works best when you have some expectation about the list's capacity ahead of time. Since `List<T>` internally allocates memory contiguously, it behaves better from a cache locality standpoint. Since `List<T>` uses an array as its backing structure, it is also very efficient for random (indexed) access.

**`LinkedList<T>` works better with problems where you need to insert or remove items from the middle or front of the list often.** Since it doesn't have to re-allocate or shift the contents of the list to do this, it will perform much better. Since `LinkedList<T>` used a linked node structure, it does not provide efficient random (indexed) access to the data. As a result, it will perform poorly if you attempt to use LINQ operators like `ElementAt()`. Linked lists generally perform worse from a cache locality standpoint since they are usually implemented to allocate nodes on demand. Some implementation use pre-cached and recycled nodes which are allocated in pools to minimize this problem - however, I don't believe the .NET implementation does so.

Answer (score 6):

Allocating many small bits of memory is much more expensive than allocating one large chunk, acquiring the global heap lock isn't that cheap.  A List<> runs rings around a LinkedList<>, cpu cache locality is king.

Comment: Memory allocation is just one part of the performance difference in behavior between `List<T>` and `LinkedList<T>` - other differences (such as shift-on-insert in List) could have a much more significant impact on performance. A lot depends on how these data structures are actually used after they are initially populated.

Comment: Well, it was nice of the OP to give a specific usage example.

Answer (score 4):

So, I "exhaustively" tested allocating and filling up various containers with various values, with and without specifying capacity, and the answers given here are basically correct. (Kudos to them for venturing hypotheses!)

Constructing a List with initial capacity is actually relatively fast; around a millisecond for as many as 100 million objects containing doubles. Constructing a List without initial capacity or constructing a LinkedList were basically instantaneous, as would be expected.

However, filling the containers revealed very significant performance differences:

Most importantly, filling the LinkedList was dooog slow. It didn't finish adding 100 million objects (simply a double wrapped in an object) in under a minute.

Filling a List constructed WITHOUT an initial capacity with 100 million objects took my test machine an average of 3732 ms. Fast.

Filling a List constructed WITH a specified initial capacity with 100 million objects took my test machine an average of 2295 ms. Very fast.

I concur with those who say the speed is due to the efficiency of manipulating contiguous memory in a cache line.

Answer (score 1):

You have to measure for your particular case. There is no way around it. I would expect one large allocation to be faster if it is small enough :).

CLR memory allocator is designed to handle huge number of small allocations well, but allocating one large block is likley faster (cost of the allocation mostly does not depend on size in CLR).

Now if your size goes above ~80K than object will be allocated on Large Objects Heap (LOH) which is slower compared to allocation from general heap and it has its own consequences (like collection will not happen in Gen 0 for such chunks).